# Antiderivative for $\sin(t^2)/2$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm taking the AP Calculus BC Exam next week and ran into this problem with no idea how to solve it. Unfortunately, the answer key didn't provide explanations, and I'd really, really appreciate it if someone could explain how to solve this problem.

The acceleration of a particle moving along the line is given by $a(4) = t\cos(t^2)$. If at time $t=0$, its velocity is $2m$ and position is $4m$, what is the position of the particle at time $t=7$?

(Calculator question; the correct answer is $18.303m$ .

I got that the equation for the velocity ($v = \sin(t^2)/2 + 2m$) but I can't seem to find its antiderivative and get the equation for the position.

A step-by-step explanation would be wonderful! :] thank you all.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $t\sin(t^2)/2$? If not, then you have to look up Fresnel integrals.

Answer (score 0):

$t \mapsto \sin(t^2)$ does not have an antiderivative you can express in elementary functions. But as you can use a calculator and you have to find a numerical value, you can evaluate it approximatively using a numerical quadrature.

Comment: How would we use the calculator to solve this? An explanation would be great.

Comment: It depends on what calculator you're using. I know that most graphing calculators have a numerical solver for integrals.

Answer (score 0):

[Fresnel integral $\mathcal S(z)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html) is defined through the following integral representation
$$\mathcal S(z)=\int_0^z \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}t^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
and $\mathcal S'(z)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}z^2\right)$.

So you have for $v(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(t^2)+v_0$
$$
x(t)-x_0=\int_0^t v(\tau)\mathrm d \tau=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sin(\tau^2)\,\mathrm{d}\tau+v_0 t
$$
that is
$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathcal S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,t\right)+v_0t+x_0
$$
and at $t=7$
$$
x(7)=x_0+7v_0+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\underbrace{\mathcal S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,7\right)}_{\approx 0.4835}$$
where we've used [WolframAlpha](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FresnelS%287+sqrt%282%2F%CF%80%29%29).